# Atalhos de teclado do VSCode para comentários

Tags: visual-studio-code

No VSCode não estou conseguindo executar alguns atalhos. O atalho de comentários, por exemplo, não funciona.

O atalho seria <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, porém todos os atalhos que precisam de uma tecla que possua mais de uma opção de letra ou símbolo não funcionam.

Por exemplo, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> funciona.

Como proceder?

Meu teclado tem na barra invertida a letra <kbd>Q</kbd> junto.

Comment: Isso eh por cousa do teclado no padrão abnt 2, ctrl+;  deve resolver

Comment: Eu passei por isso com vários comandos.
Acesse seu vscode: `file > preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`. Nessa opção irá relacionar todos os atalhos do seu vscode, se quiser filtrar, basta ir digitando os atalhos e verá algum outro comando usando mesmo atalho, basta editar...inclusive, ja aproveita para fazer otimizações nos seus comandos. Depois que estudei essa configuração, hoje meu vscode é todo personalizado com atalhos fáceis, em vez de três teclas, uso apenas uma. Faça vc tb sua personalização de comandos para agilizar seu trabalho. Desde limpar terminal, abrir e fechar terminal... Minha r

Comment: Que bom ver esta resposta - obrigado, Vivi. Acho que ajuda informar que também achava que este atalho era `Ctrl` + `/`, e a fonte disso é o próprio VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf. E cheguei nesse PDF por um link de truques e dicas do VS Code:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#vscode. Enfim. ‍♂️

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Por padrão o atalho para comentário no VSCode é o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. Você mudou a configuração?

Você também tem a opção de fazer igual o Visual Studio: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> e depois <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Resolvi o problema, de fato o atalho que você comentou funciona.Acontece que no site do vs-code eles colocaram um página com atalhos que não funcionam no meu pc. Daí a confusão, acredito que seja a configuração dos caracteres dos teclados de lá e os daqui, mas não tenho certeza.